# how to access global variable in fragment android

Tags: android, variables, fragment

I am trying to access the method local variable and assign to a global variable and try to access it to other methods code is working fine for local but not assigned to the global variable here is my code

```
global variable String spinner;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_players, container, false);
//I want to get value here
}

//private void Spinner(List<String> list)
{
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if (i>0)
    {
     String text= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     spinnerText=text;
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
});

}
```

Comment: what value are you expecting?. do you want to assign text to spinner? What is the "spinnerText" inside the listener

Comment: spiinertext is global varibale and i want to assign it a value so i can use it to somewhere else

Comment: You have declared spinner as global variable but you are using spinnerText inside the listener. Please change the variable name accordingly

Comment: its just an example i want to tell i know about that but still not working